# Rails - has_many relation causes NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations, has-many

I've the following migrations and models:

```
class CreatePlatforms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :platforms do |t|

        t.integer :user_id
        t.string :name
        t.string :platform_id
        t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|

        t.string :email
        t.string :first_name
        t.string :last_name
        t.string :gender
        t.date :birthday
        t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Platform < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :birthday
    has_many :platforms
end
```

With this definition I can create users and platforms:

```
user = User.new
platform1 = Platform.new
platform2 = Platform.new
```

And even I can associate users to platforms:

```
platform1.user = user
```

But when I try to associate platforms to users or get the platforms from a users it crashes:

```
user.platforms << user or user.platforms
NoMethodError: undefined method `platforms' for #<User:0x007f8cfd47a770>
```

Comment: You sure You have reloaded environment and the user variable itself? For instance if You have a User instance in Your Rails console, run migrations, update user model and then reload console, it still won't work because user instance was made of an older version of the class and You need to create a new one(fetch it from DB again). 

If it's happening in Your dev server environment, supply more context/details please.

Comment: reloading the console is also a very possible solution!

Comment: I've done it after migrating the database for the first time. But just in case I've reloaded the console, and the problem persists. There isn't much more context, it's a rails empty project (rails 4.0.0 ruby 2.0.0)

Comment: by the way, why do you have a string field `platform_id`? Rails generates the `ids` automatically...

Comment: You are right TheChamp, but in this case platform_id is not the id of the own model, but is the id provided by the social network (facebook_id, twitter_id, etc) platform is a social network and users could have more than one social network associated with them.

Comment: I've fixed it! TheChamp, you made me realize that this field could make a mess to rails. I've deleted this field, and it works now. (Now I'll need to look for another variable name, not platform_id)
Thanks people.

Comment: Glad it works! :) I updated my answer to reflect the solution, so that future visitors don't have to look through the comments...

And for the name, I'd go with `social_network_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem is the database field `platform_id`. This messes up rails. Simply delete it and it'll work.

Comment: That's weird because I've reloaded the console and the problem persists. How have you done it? Copy/paste of my code?

Comment: could you successfully save both the user and the platforms?

Comment: and a simple `reload!` won't do, you'll have to exit and then reopen it

Comment: I've closed and reopened the console, that's not the problem. I've tried to save all the instances, and there's no better result.
What I've noticed is that when I press tabulation, the console doesn't autocomplete for me the field "platforms" for user (ie: user.plat ), so I thing there is something wrong with the platform attribute in user model, can be?.

Comment: just to be sure that you didn't mess up with the variables: `User.first.platforms` fails?